# Subprocess Timeout in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to check the header of a website and the code works perfectly fine. However when the website does not respond within a reasonable amount of time, I added a timeout and that works too.

Unfortunately the command is not taking parameters and am struck over there. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

```
import subprocess
from threading import Timer
kill = lambda process: process.kill()
c1='curl -H'
cmd = [c1, 'google.com']
p = subprocess.Popen(
cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
my_timer = Timer(10, kill, [p])
try:
    my_timer.start()
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print stdout
finally:
    print stderr
    my_timer.cancel()
```

Error while running :

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

However if I change c1 as shown below, it works fine.

> c1='curl'

Comment: With `c1='curl'` have you tried the following: `cmd = [c1, '-H','google.com']` ?

Comment: That worked :). Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
c1='curl'
```

use

```
cmd = [c1, '-H','google.com']
```